# Strange parentheses

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was just using pydev for eclipse running python2.7 for an Intro to Programming course (which requires python3.x) and so I was using the updated print statement with parentheses

The issue that I am running into is that after my final while loop, the print() statement includes the parentheses.

`print('Number of flushes: ', flush)`

returns

```
('Number of flushes: ', 0)
```

The weird thing is that earlier in the program, before the while loop ended, the print() statement worked exactly as expected. What is going on?

Comment: Ideally you should be using the correct version of Python when you are programming, however you can also use an online interpreter to test that your code will work as expected. A popular one is [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/), just select Python3 as the language.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.x, `print` is a statement, not a function, so here:

```
print('Number of flushes: ', flush)
```

is valid syntax, but the parenthesis is interpreted as a tuple:

```
>>> print 3, 4
3 4
>>> print (3, 4)
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.X, print is a statement, not s function. Putting parenthesis around the arguments is fine when there's only  one, but when there are two or more the arguments are treated as a tuple. One way around this is to insert at the top of your code the statement, `from __future__ import print_function`. This turns the print statement into a function and gives the expected behavior when printing two or more items. However, then you must turn all the print statements into the function form.